# "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" from ssl.py: `super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)`

Tags: python, python-requests, pentaho, gevent

I am using Python 3.6.5 on the following remote server setup:

> Server: Windows 10
>
> Python: 3.6.5
>
> Requests: 2.18.4
>
> Pentaho: 8.0

When I run `request.get` against URLs in the server's command prompt, it gets the JSON as expected:

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
>>> json = response.json()
>>> print(json)
{'d': {'results': [{'_ ...
```

However when I run the same script in [CPython](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/CPython+Script+Executor) for Pentaho 8.0, I get

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

**Full log:**

```
2018/04/13 15:02:17 - Get SP Doc List.0 - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
    2018/04/13 15:02:17 - Get SP Doc List.0 - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
    2018/04/13 15:02:17 - Get SP Doc List.0 - Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pyServer.py", line 299, in execute_script
        exec (script, _global_env)
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
        return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
        return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 618, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
        timeout=timeout
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
        chunked=chunked)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
        self._validate_conn(conn)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
        conn.connect()
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 314, in connect
        cert_reqs=resolve_cert_reqs(self.cert_reqs),
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 269, in create_urllib3_context
        context.options |= options
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 465, in options
        super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 465, in options
        super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 465, in options
        super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
      [Previous line repeated 322 more times]
    RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Script:

```
import requests
import json


# By Filename
url = "https://myco.sharepoint.com/teams/dg/l/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('eRetail%20Data%20Sources')/items?..."

authtoken = "Bearer eyJ..."

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "Authorization": authtoken
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

json = response.json()
print('===========================')
print(json)
```

Comment: as @Wang Rex did, changing from https to http works ,but the correct solution would be
[here](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/941)
(it worked for me)

Comment: switching from https to http doesn't work as a general solution. What if you're beaming about bank details or checks on people's health, passwords, background-checks?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If `gevent` is installed, it needs to monkey-patch the python `socket`s to cooperate (see [documentation](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#monkey-patching) or [this github issue](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/941)).

Therefore `gevent.monkey.patch_all()` is either missing or not called early enough.

```
# at the beginning of the script
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()

# all the other stuff below, like for example
import requests
```

Answer (score 5):

Do not monkey-patch ssl:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all(ssl=False)
```

Comment: If I'm doing this, I get `RuntimeError: cannot release un-acquired lock`

Comment: @Vladimir apart from the really obvious reason, what makes you say this? Is there documentation for your statement somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

I figured out that my issue is because I introduced locust in another place of my application, which uses gevent==1.2.2. After I commented out the gevent import statements, this recursion issue was gone. It is worth checking if you have introduced gevent somewhere in your app.

---

I ran into the same error recently, and haven't found any way to solve this. I had to use http instead of https in my situation, although it's really **dangerous**.

Answer (score 1):

```
from gevent import monkey as curious_george
# curious_george.patch_all(thread=False, select=False)
def stub(*args, **kwargs):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
    pass
```

Comment: I was  searching for a similar issue and found a [closed issue](https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests/issues/103) 
The above solution worked for me

Comment: can't upvote this enough ) it's just, I have uncommented curious_george.patch_all(thread=False, select=False) line

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I use `reqto`, the solution was to put a try: except: block around it:

```
    peers = None

    try:
        res = reqto.get(f"https://{domain}/api/v1/instance/peers", headers=headers, timeout=5)
        peers = res.json()

        if not res.ok or res.status_code >= 400:
            print("WARNING: Cannot fetch peers:", domain)
            update_last_error(domain, res)

    except:
        print("WARNING: Some error during get():", domain)
```

<strike>If this doesn't work for you, you might want to cleanup your `~/.local/lib/python3/site-packages/` directory. Some old remaining files have caused a freezer and that no file was fetched from remote. Caused me a lot of hours to discover it!</strike>

Nope, not working! Maybe just pure coincidence!

For my script, I had to `import reqto` in `fba.commands` module while it was not referenced there. I mad a separate branch so you can find it out yourself: https://git.mxchange.org/?p=fba.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/broken/missing-import-reqto
Just put that said import line in the said file' header where the other `import` line exist and that code will work!