# Request Method Recursion Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

The request dot get method is not working properly.
currently, I am using Python 3.8.10. Before it was working fine but now it happens the issue.
please find the code and error message below for reference.

Code

```
x = requests.get('https://w3schools.com', timeout=10)
print(x.status_code)
```

Error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/root/api-server/server/rest.py", line 141, in getprice
    data = General().getprice()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask_caching/__init__.py", line 795, in decorated_function
    rv = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/api-server/server/methods/general.py", line 41, in getprice
    result = utils.getprice()
  File "/root/api-server/server/utils.py", line 180, in getprice
    x = requests.get('https://api.widecoin.org/info', timeout=10)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 368, in connect
    self.ssl_context = create_urllib3_context(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 273, in create_urllib3_context
    context.options |= options
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 602, in options
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 602, in options
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 602, in options
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
  [Previous line repeated 476 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" from ssl.py: \`super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.\_\_set\_\_(self, value)\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49820173/recursionerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-from-ssl-py-supersslcontex)

Comment: from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all(ssl=False) but now working