# Recursion Error when s3 client is initialized within Inference script for my SageMaker Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-sagemaker, gevent

I need help with this recursion error maximum recursion depth exceeded from boto3. This happens when I initialize an s3 client in my inference script to allow me read s3 objects. Your insights will be deeply appreciated! Similar issue posted 2 months ago here: [AWS SageMaker Endpoint: Maximum Recursion Depth Exceeded Error When Calling boto3.client("s3")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77786275/aws-sagemaker-endpoint-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-error-when-calling-boto)
Here is the relevant code block responsible for the error:

```
def get_video_bytes_from_s3(bucket_name, key):
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        video_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket= bucket_name, Key=key)
        video_bytes = video_object['Body'].read()
        return video_bytes
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to fetch video from S3: {e}")
```

Error log from CloudWatch:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sagemaker/python_service.py", line 423, in _handle_invocation_post
    res.body, res.content_type = handlers(data, context)
  File "/opt/ml/model/code/inference.py", line 156, in handler
    video_bytes = get_video_bytes_from_s3(key)
  File "/opt/ml/model/code/inference.py", line 16, in get_video_bytes_from_s3
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 92, in client
    return _get_default_session().client(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 299, in client
    return self._session.create_client(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 997, in create_client
    client = client_creator.create_client(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 159, in create_client
    client_args = self._get_client_args(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 490, in _get_client_args
    return args_creator.get_client_args(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/args.py", line 137, in get_client_args
    endpoint = endpoint_creator.create_endpoint(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 409, in create_endpoint
    http_session = http_session_cls(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 323, in __init__
    self._manager = PoolManager(**self._get_pool_manager_kwargs())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 341, in _get_pool_manager_kwargs
    'ssl_context': self._get_ssl_context(),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 350, in _get_ssl_context
    return create_urllib3_context()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 139, in create_urllib3_context
    context.options |= options
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 620, in options
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 620, in options
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 620, in options
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
  [Previous line repeated 479 more times]
```

I have tried monkey patching using `gevent` i.e. by placing this

```
monkey.patch_all()
```

at the top of my imports but it doesn't resolve the issue. Your insights are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to circumvent the problem by setting this environment variable in my model container `SAGEMAKER_GUNICORN_WORKER_CLASS = "sync"`. Inspired by this issue https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/issues/1561.